# LinkedLists in Java; making the last node on the list point to the first node rather than contain null

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm trying to figure out how to write a method that would modify the last node in a linkedlist and change it from `null` to the first node when passed the first pointer from the linked list.

I tried this which turned into a error:

```
public void blah()

{

Node p = first;

while (p != null)

{

p = p.link;

}

p.x = p.first;
}
```

Comment: public void blah()
   {
   Node p = first;
   while (p != null)
   {
   p = p.link
   }
   p.x = p.first;
}

Comment: What was the exception?  Usually they are helpful in diagnosing a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void blah()  {
    Node p = first;
    while (p.link != null) {
        p = p.link;
    }
    p.link = first;
}
```

Be aware that this will create a circular list, that's what you intend, right? Also, I'm assuming that `first` is an attribute of the class where `blah()` resides.

Answer (score 1):

This would do the job for you.

```
public void blah(Node list){
   Node firstNode = list;
   while (list.link != null){
      list = list.link;
   }
   list.link = firstNode;
}
```

The 'first' reference you've used in the code suggests that its a member variable. If you want to read more on Singly Linked lists in Java thoroughly, follow this [link](http://tech.bragboy.com/2010/01/linked-lists.html).